# Escrever em um .txt remotamente com JS

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma maneira de eu escrever em um documento de texto (com permissões de escrita pra usuários anônimos) que está dentro de um servidor, utilizando Javascript?

Comment: Mas o meu caso se aplica a um arquivo num servidor

Comment: Também acho que não é duplicata, mas é mais complicado ainda do que o que foi indicado. A resposta curta é "não, não dá". O que dá é pro JS chamar um serviço num servidor remoto que faça o que você quiser lá, seja em PHP, CGI ou qq outra tecnologia no servidor.

Comment: @Bacco, aquela pergunta lá não especifica "servidor", mas eu até considero implicito; o Zuul orientou a resposta ao "computador da pessoa", mas nada impede uma nova resposta lá; as duas linhas desta pergunta só diferem daquela em "servidor" e "usuário anônimo".

Comment: @brasofilo É uma daquelas coisas que fica numa zona nebulosa. Mas não veja isso como uma crítica ao fechamento, é só realmente pelo fato de aquela não resolver o problema do OP por enquanto. Tanto que nem votei pra reabrir, ate porque, acho que o comentário que eu fiz meio que responde a questão.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ver mais respostas lá na dup, uma recompensa de algum user 10k+ seria legal :P @Bacco

Comment: Seria legal se fosse de um user 20k+ (sobrou pro @mgibsonbr :D )

Comment: @admin_, publiquei uma nova resposta lá na duplicata, agora falta uma solução com jQuery, mas a web está cheia de exemplos disso, se por acaso implementar um legal adicione uma resposta também.